# RAID driver to choose for slipstreaming XP installation on ASUS P5S800

Tags: windows-xp, installation, sata, nlite

I'm trying to install Windows XP on my new SATA drive but I need to first slipstream the drivers with nLite.   I've done this before, but not on an **ASUS P5S800 - VM** motherboard.

I'm not used to the number of choices it gives me for drivers in SiS chipsets.  When I look through the folder that I downloaded from ASUS for the RAID driver, I see many folders with different versions of the driver. Here are the folders or versions given.

- 180ob
- 964_180
- 965
- 966_968

**What drivers do I need to add in order to get XP on my SATA disk?**

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make a 'driver disk' using the software you can download from your vendor. That disk will contain all the drivers the Windows setup needs to recognize your controller, so if you want to use them with nlite, simply copy them from the disk (or folder where they are, it depends).

Another question is if you really need those drivers. If you put your controller/chipset in 'AHCI' mode, setup will probably recognize your controller and disks right away.

An easy way to test this is to boot a vanilla XP install CD and see if you can get it to recognize your disk without any additional drivers.